# Another vs the other when there are two in total

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> 1. I have two uncles, one in Chicago and **another** in Dallas. (  From a workbook)
> 2. Stewart summed up the general feeling of the American public today, saying that CNBC and the financial news media could help educate Americans, showing the idea that there are **two markets**: one for the long term that average Americans invest in and are encouraged to invest in, and **another**, fast-paced market that exists away from the public eye. ([Source](https://books.google.ca/books?id=4K1eiLACNJgC&pg=PT120&lpg=PT120&dq=%22Stewart%20summed%20up%20the%20general%20feeling%20of%20the%20American%20public%20today,%20saying%20that%20CNBC%20and%20the%20financial%20news%20media%20could%20help%20educate%20Americans,%20showing%20the%20idea%20that%20there%20are%20two%20markets:%20one%20for%20the%20long%20term%20that%20average%20Americans%20invest%20in%20and%20are%20encouraged%20to%20invest%20in,%20and%20another,%20fast-paced%20market%20that%20exists%20away%20from%20the%20public%20eye.%22&source=bl&ots=o148b2Lnsh&sig=ACfU3U06JEPe2VA88d83LiLxwqSmREwZFA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVtrKM9dWCAxU0JX0KHV4-C00Q6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Stewart%20summed%20up%20the%20general%20feeling%20of%20the%20American%20public%20today%2C%20saying%20that%20CNBC%20and%20the%20financial%20news%20media%20could%20help%20educate%20Americans%2C%20showing%20the%20idea%20that%20there%20are%20two%20markets%3A%20one%20for%20the%20long%20term%20that%20average%20Americans%20invest%20in%20and%20are%20encouraged%20to%20invest%20in%2C%20and%20another%2C%20fast-paced%20market%20that%20exists%20away%20from%20the%20public%20eye.%22&f=false))
> 3. Once the Fed was in place, there were **two sets of rules** when it came to money: One set of rules for people who work for money, and **another** set of rules for the rich who print money. ([Source](https://books.google.ca/books?id=4K1eiLACNJgC&pg=PT13&lpg=PT13&dq=%22Once%20the%20Fed%20was%20in%20place,%20there%20were%20**two%20sets%20of%20rules**%20when%20it%20came%20to%20money:%20One%20set%20of%20rules%20for%20people%20who%20work%20for%20money,%20and%20**another**%20set%20of%20rules%20for%20the%20rich%20who%20print%20money.%22&source=bl&ots=o148b2Meoj&sig=ACfU3U0xSxPHCY1Rj47M8f5qBHIL-Aq9tw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYl4yq9dWCAxUvHjQIHTd4C4IQ6AF6BAgJEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Once%20the%20Fed%20was%20in%20place%2C%20there%20were%20**two%20sets%20of%20rules**%20when%20it%20came%20to%20money%3A%20One%20set%20of%20rules%20for%20people%20who%20work%20for%20money%2C%20and%20**another**%20set%20of%20rules%20for%20the%20rich%20who%20print%20money.%22&f=false))

I think if there are two elements in a set. The way to refer to the second element is by "*the other", not "another*".  So do you think the sentences above are totally fine or bad grammar, but acceptable？

Comment: English speakers do not (unless they are _very_ unusual) frame their utterances so as not to offend against the tenets of set theory.

Comment: Use of "another" in these examples is perfectly fine. However there's a missing comma after Chicago in your first sentence. Check the source of the quote. It could be typo.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks. I'm missing a "and"

Comment: @ForOU - **an** "and".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey   You mean native speakers could often break grammar rules.  Do I get you correctly?

Comment: Grammar rules and set theory are not identical.

Comment: Some (not all) grammar 'rules' are sometimes treated more flexibly by native speakers than they are by the authors of ESL texts and teachers in that subject.

Comment: @ForOU There are no grammatical errors in the examples. I'm voting to close this question as it is based on a non-existent grammar rule.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Thank you.  The purpose of this question is more or less to find out whether this "rule"  is one of those flexible ones.

Comment: @BillyKerr Okay,  actually doubts have been dispelled.

Comment: @ForOU - it's not a grammar rule.  An example: There are two apples. Here is one apple, and here is another.  <<--- there is absolutely nothing wrong here.  Another here simply means "a different/additional apple".  You could use "the other", but this is not a requirement.

Comment: If you are looking for a definition, here is what the OED says: Another: sense: "II.4.
A different thing of the same type or kind; a different one."  - source: Oxford English Dictionary, s.v. “another, pron., adj., & adv.”, September 2023. <https://doi.org/10.1093/OED/6299635519>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are perfectly acceptable. Either of *the other* and *another* is fine in those examples. But, particularly in the third example, *another* gives it a slightly different meaning. In sentences like

> There are two sets of rules: one for normal people, and another for the rich

the *another* emphasizes the contrast between the sets of rules, the “otherness” of those rules that apply to the rich. Replacing *another* in that sentence by *the other* renders it more nearly a simple, neutral presentation of the sets of rules.

You could compare the difference in meaning to what’s going on between

> The hotel provided **different** meals for guests and their pets

and

> The hotel provided **separate** meals for whites and blacks.

The former is more matter-of-fact. After all, people and goldfish have utterly different dietary requirements. The latter highlights a racial segregation that is now, happily, illegal.

Thus, as is so often the case, context and one’s intended meaning matter a lot.

Comment: I agree the fine nuance of difference in example #3. But I think it stems from the fact that ***the other*** "neutrally" references *"the other **of two**"*, whereas ***another*** implies there are (more precisely, *could be*) a number of alternative "sets of rules". By *further* implication, although the vast majority of "ordinary people" work for money, and are thus governed by the *main* rules, the rich people who actually print the money could take their pick from a number of alternative rules that might suit them better. They hold all the aces in this particular game.

Comment: Thanks.  May I ask of the related question? *Since our plane was leaving soon we were moved to the front of the line while _(the) others___ remained at the back.*  Do you think this sentence is fine with or without "the",  just as the sentences in OP？

Comment: Each is grammatically correct, but they are not interchangeable because they convey different meanings. The *others* version conveys that there exist people who remained at the back, whereas the *the others* version assumes that one’s addressees understand some group of people whom one is distinguishing from the people referred to by *we*. Repeating from my answer, “as is so often the case, context and one’s intended meaning matter a lot.”